# Xcode Swift: is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1

Tags: ios, swift, warnings

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Everytime I click on the Sign Up button on the left view controller. I get this warning saying:

> "2017-09-10 11:14:50.573574+0800 Custom Fonts[1413:62959] [Warning] <UIVisualEffectView 0x7fc1e1e203a0> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1."

I checked the alpha setting of my visual effects, they're all set to 1. How can I fix this?

My Code:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpVC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func dismissPopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //signup logic
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D++being+asked+to+animate+its+opacity).

Answer (score 0):

Change the animated to "false",

```
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```